# Cigarette on Pesach

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, tobacco-cig-smoking

Is there a problem of Chometz with Smoking  on Pesach?

Comment: Don't forget the other major problem: Smoking on Yomtov. Is smoking still considered a Davar HaShaveh Lechol Nefesh? http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6818/are-cigarettes-on-yomtov-a-davar-hashaveh-lechol-nefesh

Comment: @Yahu, for argument's sake let's say it's chol hamoed.

Comment: Don't forget another major problem: this question assumes that it is permissible to smoke on a regular weekday. I would challenge this assumption.

Comment: @YaakovEllis http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10513/732

Comment: Smoking any day of the year is already asur on account of pikuach nefesh. It's also incredibly inconsiderate when done in public. Also on Yom Tov how would you plan to light it, from a candle? I'm not familiar enough to tell you whether cigaretts are considered leaven bread, however.

Answer (score 3):

See here even the Mishnah Berurah disallows tabaco
[PDF of Chometz and Smokiing](http://www.shtaygen.net/horadot/psach/aishun.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The [Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30483&pgnum=199) reports that the Previous Rebbe said that the Rebbe Rashab (the fifth Lubavitcher Rebbe) would smoke on Pesach after the Afikoman.

The Rebbe Rashab [also requested](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30483&pgnum=80) from his son (the previous Lubavitcher Rebbe) to bring him cigarettes for Pesach.

However, the bulletin put out by the Crown Heights Beis Din warns that people have found Chometz in cigarettes lately, so one should avoid them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just about any food, personal care, or medical product is required to reveal far more about its formulation than cigarettes do. So it's incredibly hard to tell what they're putting in there.