# Which communities do not allow women to smoke?

Tags: women, communities, tobacco-cig-smoking

Which communities do not allow women to smoke? Satmar?

If yes, is it an official or implicit rule ?

Comment: I think that is a social thing (that smoking is more frowned upon with women) not a religious one. And it isn't just in Jewish circles.

Comment: Thanks. I know that women smokes in some communities. I guess it is more frowned upon in haredi communities, isnt it ?

Comment: It probably is. It is frowned upon for men as well, but much less so.

Comment: I think Yishai is right,its generally frowned on. someone argued that smokers have a bigger burden on shabbos.

Comment: question assumes anyone is permitted to smoke. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10513/is-one-allowed-to-smoke?rq=1

Comment: @eramm No it doesn't.

Comment: No I was not. My question was about women, not women and men. I am asking for the ban's reasons for women.