# Is one allowed to smoke on minor fast days?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, tobacco-cig-smoking

There are various opinions on whether it is [ever permissible to smoke](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10513/3483), with rabbinic opinion shifting more toward "no" in recent years, but among those who permit smoking generally, is it permissible to smoke on [minor fast days](http://www.jewfaq.org/holidaye.htm), such as Tzom Gedaliah, the 17th of Tammuz, Ta'anit Esther, or the 10th of Tevet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh (Yalqut Yosef) clearly states in Orahh Hayim 550:23 -

> מותר לעשן בימי תעניות צבור, זולת בתשעה באב שראוי להמנע מעישון סיגריות, ובפרט בפרהסיא, כדי שלא יסיח דעתו מאבילות היום. ובעת הצורך מותר לעשן גם בתשעה באב כשעושה כן בצינעא, ובפרט לאחר חצות היום. ובשאר צומות, אף הנוהגים לעשן ביום טוב על ידי הדלקה מאש לאש, דחשיב אצלם לענין זה כאוכל נפש, אפילו הכי מותר להם לעשן בתענית צבור.‏

That is:

> It's permissible to smoke on communal fast days. This is to the exclusion of the ninth of Av, on which it's fitting to refrain from smoking cigarettes, in particular in public, so that he not distract himself from the day's mourning; but in case of need it's permissible to smoke even on the ninth of Av when doing so in private, in particular after midday. On other fast days, even those who are accustomed to smoke on holidays (by passing a flame from another fire) because they consider it like food may nonetheless smoke on a communal fast.

Answer (score 3):

The Mishna Berura ([555:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=65)) rules one should not smoke on any of the 4 [Temple-related (?)] fasts unless one is extremely addicted whereby he can be lenient in private. This leniency was not given to Tisha bAv night or morning.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the health concerns of every day, there is no specific prohibition on smoking during minor fast days.

Comment: A source would improve your answer.

Comment: Is it an איסור to kill oneself?